# Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense for Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm

Remember back in CRM 2011 days, there is this XrmPageTemplate.js file from CRM SDK? Visual Studio will give you nice JavaScript intellisense if you refer to this file from your JavaScript. My question is how do you do the same for CRM 2015? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub you can find the [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/) project containing TypeScript definition files, among which those for [Dynamics CRM](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/ffceea9dd124d277c4597c7bd12930666ec074c5/xrm).

Add the definition file to your web project and name it, say, "Xrm.intellisense.ts". Reference it in your Javascript file by adding the following line at the top of the page. (You will probably need to adjust the path.)

```
/// <reference path="/Scripts/References/XrmPage.intellisense.ts"/>
```

Intellisense will work great with Resharper.

Comment: Thanks Henk! The Definitely Typed project definitely looks interesting. However I am not sure how to use it with the CRM Developer Toolkit. The CRM Developer Toolkit only supports VS 2012 but the latest version of TypeScript doesn't as far as I know. Yes, I probably can switch between VS 2012 and VS 2015. Nevertheless, that is a bit clunky.

Comment: Well, I can only advise not to use the CRM Developer Toolkit. It has its issues and was discontinued by Microsoft. Instead you could consider the CRM Solution Manager; this is really great for developing web resources.

Comment: Unfortunately, the company I am working with is still using CRM Developer Toolkit. I know CRM Solution Manager is good but there is no point to get it just for myself as other colleagues will have difficulties open my CRM solution. I guess it is about the time to try to convince my manager again to make the investment.

Comment: The above solution will work with VS 2015 + CRM Solution Manager (Need Purchase) at the point of time I am writing this comment.

Comment: not sure for certain if MS has discountinued CRM Developer Toolkit. Folks, please vote up the following MS Connect issue for some response from MS regarding to the topic, thanks! https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/1089946/dynamics-crm-developer-toolkit-for-crm-2015-visual-studio-2013